# Figuring the correct distribution model for apps with different branding but mostlty shared code - fix and deploy once for all apps

Tags: android, download, installation, distribution, apk

I'm producing an application for multiple clients. Each of these apps only slightly differs (in the ui presentation) from the others and almost all of the other code is identical.

In the best case scenario I would brand something like a boot-strap app for each client so they could have their logo on a separate app in the market. Once a user installed a client's app it would download the core functionality, set some prefs and launch as if it had come from a single download. This way I could get the benefit of updating for bug fixes once rather than for each application (slated for 20-30 by end of year.) I've read that this isn't possible because of security measures though (and additional visits to the market place for the second download or having to allow installation from unknown sources isn't acceptable.)

I'm thinking that worst-case/only-case might be to include this shared code in each application and create some batch build and deploy once updates are ready.

I'm looking for a .dll like approach for economy of effort and safety.

I'd appreciate any input on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The java equivalent of a dll is a jar file. You can extract all of your shared functionality into a library project that compiles into a jar and then include that as a library in your other projects.

Comment: At runtime then, can I download and execute/use this jar from another apk? The info I've found says that it needs to be an apk itself and is then subject to the rules I mentioned above.

Comment: In android's case, the jar would be included in the individual apks at compile time. Each app can then be downloaded separately from the market but you can skip the potentially complicated download step you mentioned in your original question.

Comment: Yeah, I'd really be happy to implement the complex part though if it were allowed - two downloads is not an option.